# Projections of Covariance Matrices in Tangent space.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

[Pervaiz et al. (2020)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1053811920300914) suggest that you could project multiple covariate matrices in tangent space using the formula: $$\overrightarrow{C}=\log_{m}({C_{G}^{-1/2}CC_{G}^{-1/2}})$$

- $C_{G}$ is the euclidean mean of all covariance matrixes
- $C$ is an individual covariance matrix that should be projected to the tangent space

If I correctly read the formula, the first operation (1) to perform is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{C_{G}}}$. (2) Secondly, I would multiply the result of the first operation with $C$ and (3) the result of that I would again multiply with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{C_{G}}}$. (4) As the last step, I would have to get the matrix logarithm of that.

After steps (1), (3), and (4) I check if the matrix is still symmetric and positive semidefinite, which was true in all cases with some imprecision, which I thought originated in float imprecision. Is that a valid sanity check?

When I performed these steps in said order, I ended up with a matrix full of complex numbers. I wondered if the complex numbers are a consequence of negative covariance values, but thought that would not be a good explanation as the negative sign only is an indicator of the relationship's direction between two variables and thus changing the direction of the relationship should not change the strength of the connection. Therefore, I asked myself if the complex numbers after the application of the matrix logarithm could be caused by float imprecision or are in fact an expected result after the application of the formula above.

Edit: Or is it possible to read $C_{G}^{-1/2}$ as $(C_{G}^{-1})^{1/2}$ and thus as $\sqrt{(C_{G}^{-1})}$. When the matrix is invertible as suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675866/is-the-negative-power-of-a-matrix-defined). Nevertheless, I end up with complex values at the end, therefore my follow-up questions are the same.